# Create a matrix of a custom class in R

Tags: r, class, oop, matrix

I need to create a custom class to represent a person in R with some attributes like (age = numeric, value = character, tax = numeric) and, later, a matrix of this class with some cells with random values. The values will change over time. How can I create the class, the matrix and update the matrix? I searched, but did not find any nice references to help with this.

Something like this in Java:

//Person.java

public class Person {

```
private String name;

private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

}

//Test.java

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person[][] person = new Person[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            person[i][j] = new Person();
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            person[i][j].setAge((int) (100 * Math.random()));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: well that would be impossible with a matrix

Comment: Is there other way to do it with another data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data frame, but it is tricky.

Or you can create three matrices: age, value, tax

Comment: Hi, user3587399. I am trying to avoid using 3 matrices. Maybe, there´s an OOP way to do. I know how to do in Java, but I want to use R instead.

Comment: ## You can create a matrix of lists (see Hadley's book 
    ## adv-r.had.co.nz/
    ## for more details):

    db = matrix(list(), 10, 10);

    for (i in 1:10) {
      for (j in 1:10) {
 db[[i,j]]=list(name=paste0("name", i, j), value=i*10+j);
 }
    }

    db[[i,j]];

Comment: Thanks, I will search for it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `attributes`?

```
y = matrix( rnorm(9), 3, 3)
attributes(y) = c(attributes(y),name="John",value=100,tax=300)
y
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.4574986 0.5482117  0.6947294
[2,] -0.7411159 0.8509640 -1.4962432
[3,] -0.0185566 0.8336693 -0.7918734
attr(,"name")
[1] "John"
attr(,"value")
[1] 100
attr(,"tax")
[1] 300
```

You could also create a `list` that contains a `matrix` and then change it's class to be of a "Person" class. Then you can create S3 methods like `summary.Person`.

```
x = list(name="John",age=33,value=100,tax=300,matrix=matrix(NA,2,2))
class(x) = c("Person","list")

summary.Person = function(x) paste(x$name,x$age)
summary(x)
[1] "John 33"
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. I updated the post with some Java code. Maybe, It turns the things clearer. :)

Comment: R is object oriented, but in a much different way than Java. You won't be able to replicate some of the things from Java in R because you're not meant to. Google "Advanced R Programming" if you want to learn more about it.